# How to show Form2 inside Form1 panel using Delphi 11 and TMS web core?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, tms, tms-web-core

My problem is that Form2 won't show inside Form1 panel in the code below:

```
procedure TForm1.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LResult: integer;
  newform: TForm2;

begin
  newform := TForm2.Create(Self);
  newform.Caption := 'test form';

  newform.Parent :=  WebPanel1; // this is the problem it doesn't work

  newform.Popup := false;

  // used to manage Back button handling to close subform
  window.location.hash := 'main';

  // load file HTML template + controls
  await(TForm2, newform.Load());

  // init controls values after loading
  newform.WebLabel1.caption := newform.WebLabel1.caption + ' is working!';

  try
    // excute form and wait for close
    LResult := await(TModalResult, newform.Execute);

    WebLabel1.Caption := WebLabel1.Caption + newform.ModalResult.ToString();

    ShowMessage('Form 2 is closed!');
  finally
    newform.Free;
  end;

end;
```

I'm trying to use VCL way to achieve this so far but the form is not displaying inside the panel!

```
newform.Parent :=  WebPanel1; // this is the problem it doesn't work no error messages
```

another approach is:

```
frm :=  TForm2.CreateNew(WebPanel1.ElementID, nil);
```

Which is working perfectly however it will not act as a modal like my code above to give back a result.

My goal is to display Form2 inside a panel in Form1 and wait for the user to close it so it can return a result to Form1 (a simple modal form way).

any way to do this please?

Comment: Have you set `Visible` property of your second form to `True`? By default when you create additional forms in Delphi their `Visibility` property is always set to `False`.  So either set your second form's the `Visible` property to `True` at design-time or call `newForm.Show;`. But definitely don't call `newForm.ShowModal` when this form is shown within other form as you will block receiving any windows messages to it since they need to go through parent form message que which is currently being blocked by modality of your second form.

Comment: Any way nesting forms within other forms can lead to some other problems so it is better to use frames for this instead. As for returning message from this "second form" to the main form there are plenty other ways you can achieve that. Main question here would be how are you waiting for the received message in your main form.

Comment: I don't have Delphi 11 (I'm on 10.4), neither `WebCore`, but it seems you are missing a `newform.show;` after setting the forms parent. I also do not undestand why you need to call 'newform.Popup := false;'

Comment: @SilverWarior This code `LResult := await(TModalResult, newform.Execute);` as mentioned above waits for the form till closes then save the return message in a LResult. also setting for Visibility doesn't affect anything here

Comment: @Tom Brunberg no need for `newform.show` as again `LResult := await(TModalResult, newform.Execute);' will display the form but the problem it is not inside the panel, it is covering the whole page!

Comment: After more testing: `newform.show` or `newform.ShowModal` or `LResult := await(TModalResult, newform.Execute);` all lead to the same result which is Form2 out of the panel covering the whole page

Comment: @Dreamer64 Can you please show the code of the `Await` method?  Also have you considered that your form might be positioned outside of panel boundaries due to `Top` and `Left` properties being to large?

Comment: @SilverWarior the `Await` method is part of TMS web core, their latest update came with it so you can wait for a process to finish without blocking your entire code.

Comment: Best to check the TMS support site.. many helpful people there. That said, I'm not sure what you want to do is possible.. you can simulate it in a way using callbacks etc..which I've done successfully.

Comment: Have you sorted out the issue? You know you can answer your own questions, don't you. I'm interested as I can not reproduce it with std forms.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg Yes, I can share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon request I'm answering my own question with code comments, Thanks for your interest.

```
  public
    { Public declarations }
    newform: TWebform; // I moved it here just to reuse it anywhere
  end;    

    procedure TForm1.WebLabel1Click(Sender: TObject);
    
      procedure AfterCreate(AForm: TObject);
        begin
          { Do What you want to that form after creation }
        end;
    
    begin
      // check if it's there then clear it that is useful for multiple time use 
      if Assigned(newform) then
      begin
        newform.Close;
        newform := nil;
      end;

      // Just a double check if its cleared for testing purposes
      if newform <> nil then
         begin
           showMessage('Form Still Exsists!');
           exit;
         end;

      // the creation starts here
      newform := TForm2.CreateNew(WebPanel1.ElementID, @AfterCreate); //<-- this line did the trick!

      newform.Caption := 'test form';
      newform.Popup := false;
    
      // used to manage Back button handling to close subform
      window.location.hash := 'main';
    end;
```